# Android Talkback Accessibility: ToolTip vs Title/ContentDescription

Tags: android, talkback, accessibility

For menu items, it seems like the tooltip text is being read out in Talkback along with the title/content description. Is this the expected behavior? It seems to me like the ToolTip text should not be read out by Talkback, given the current behavior makes it impossible to have a different ToolTip text vs Talkback text (I would rather not have the word "button" appear in the tooltip)

With the below code, the following is read out by talkback: "Edit, Edit button".

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_edit"
        android:title="Edit button"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

MenuItemCompat.setTooltipText(mEditMenuItem, "Edit");
```

Comment: It seems like if you have the same text for the button title and the tooltip text, it will only read once.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set content description the same as TooltipText

MenuItemCompat.setTooltipText(mEditMenuItem, "Edit");
MenuItemCompat.setContentDescription(mEditMenuItem, "Edit");